# The parameter has a dependency on a non-existent parameter

Tags: symfony, prestashop

I have a password in parameters in services.yaml,
for example "xxx%xxxxx%xx" and when i want to do GetParameter
it returns me only "xxxxx" and error 500

```
parameters:
     api_passwd: "x%xxxxx%xxx"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw8ih.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, [avoid using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in your questions.  Just copy/paste the relevant portions of the error into your code.

Secondly it sort of looks like you are testing in production mode?  You should have gotten a completely different error message.  Make yourself a simple console command for testing these sorts of things.

In any event, Symfony treats % as a rather special character.  In general, avoid using % in your yaml values.  Never really noticed it myself which is why I am actually posting an answer.  The workaround is to double up the % character.  Basically escaping it.

```
parameters:
    api_passwd: "x%%xxxxx%%xxx"
```

The extra % characters will be stripped out when you retrieve the value.